# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected embedding_2_input to have shape (500,) but got array with shape (1,)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, sentiment-analysis

**I have Trained the model using keras and When trying to predict the values with raw text data using the keras sentiment analysis**
**Getting the Raw Data from SQL server**

*Here is my Code*

```
x_data = [clean_text]
x_data_series = pd.Series(x_data)
raw_text = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(x_data_series)
raw_text = pad_sequences(raw_text, maxlen=1, dtype='int32', value=0)
for x_t in raw_text:
  sentiment = model.predict(x_t,batch_size=2)[0]
  y_classes = sentiment.argmax(axis=-1)
```

Getting the Error on this Line

```
sentiment = model.predict(x_t,batch_size=2)[0]
```

**Error**

***ValueError: Error when checking input: expected embedding_2_input to have shape (500,) but got array with shape (1,)***

Answer (score 0):

`model.predict()` expects minibatches of data, but you're passing only one sample. You can convert your sample to minibatch of size 1 by creating additional dimension in your `x_t`:

```
sentiment = model.predict(x_t[np.newaxis, :],batch_size=2)[0]
```

Comment: Now getting the Following Error : ValueError: Error when checking input: expected embedding_2_input to have shape (500,) but got array with shape (14,)

Comment: Share your model's code, please, it's impossible to determine the reason of error without it.